# Detecting when device in cardboard headset in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm building a Unity Cardboard app, and would like to detect when the device is in the headset. The NFC in theory has this data, but it does not seem to be exposed in the API. I would like to have the app automatically enter VR mode when in the headset, without the user needing to toggle in and out of a VR mode.

Basically, I want Cardboard.vrModeEnabled to be automatically updated when you enter or exit a headset.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It used to be in the (non-Unity) SDK but was deprecated, for several reasons.  For one, the NFC sensors on phones are placed in different places, so the detection was not uniformly reliable.  For another, using the sensor this way drains battery quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of cardboard models on the market. a lot of them don't come with an NFC tag. so i wouldn't count on it.

Best approach for me is to start in VR mode, when the user touches the screen, disable VR mode for 10 seconds since the last touch and then go back to VR mode.